# How to add different layoutmanagers to MergeApdater

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

So I want that each section of my mergeadapter has a different layoutmanager, for example, my first adapter should have a GridLayoutManager, the second one a LinearLayoutManager and the third one is a viewPagerAdapter

So, for instance, how do I setup the recyclerview that this MergeAdapter will use and know the different layoutmanagers for each adapter ?

This is the code from the documentation, since we have just 1 recyclerview in which we inflate all the adapters inside with different views, I want to know how to setup a gridlayoutmanager to the first adapter and so one to the other adapters

```
val firstAdapter: FirstAdapter = …
val secondAdapter: SecondAdapter = …
val thirdAdapter: ThirdAdapter = …
val mergeAdapter = MergeAdapter(firstAdapter, secondAdapter, 
     thirdAdapter)
recyclerView.adapter = mergeAdapter
```

since I do

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: It's impossible - `LayoutManager` is the class responsible for laying out the views and determining what items to bind from an adapter, not the other way around.

Comment: but how it should be impossible ? so there is no way to use MergeAdapter with different views layoutmanagers ? if is designed like that is not usefull at all